# How to convert time datatype of SQL Server to C# datetime data type?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a scenario where I need to convert a value of `TIME` datatype in SQL Server to C# server time.

In SQL Server:

```
10:10
```

Comment: In C# you can use TimeSpan object, have you tried with it?

Comment: While using time span object , i am getting an error specified cast is not valid

Comment: Show us how you are “using time span object”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting time data type of SQL Server to Date time in C#

Cast the DataReader object to `SqlDataReader` using `((SqlDataReader)reader)` and use the `GetTimeSpan` method.

```
TimeSpan myTimeSpan = ((SqlDataReader)reader).GetTimeSpan(reader.GetOrdinal("Column Name"));

object.time= new DateTime(myTimeSpan.Ticks);
```