# How to Get Time from DateTime in "hh:mm tt" format in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Sir
I'm getting the Date in the correct format but the time not in the correct format.
I want the time in this format "hh: mm tt" (Example:10:20 AM)
I am using 'date' datatype for Date and 'time' for Time in SQL Server-2014
please help me

```
 for each(var item in Model)
 {
   <tr>
       <td>
           @(item.LoginTime?.ToString("hh:mm tt")) 
       </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Comment: what is this `.t` in your code `@(item.LoginTime?.t("hh:mm:ss tt"))` 
and what type are you using to hold the date and time in C# ?

maybe you meant  `item.LoginTime?.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")` ?

Comment: did this `@(item.LoginTime?.ToString("hh:mm tt"))` helped ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this formatting

```
@(item.LoginTime?.ToString("hh:mm tt"))
```

Comment: What is .t in @(item.LoginTime?.t("hh:mm tt")) may be it should be .ToString

Comment: @BhushanMuttha I commented this exact message in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

If you are using time data type, you need to convert it first into DateTime. Then you can do your thing:

```
@(item.LoginTime?.ToString("hh:mm tt"))
```

[How to convert time datatype of SQL Server to C# datetime data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34200527/how-to-convert-time-datatype-of-sql-server-to-c-sharp-datetime-data-type)